# Semantically, should Commands and Converters be closer to Views or ViewModels?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, ivalueconverter, icommand

I'm wondering if in MVVM I should design Converters and Commands be closer to Views or ViewModels. It's a gray zone for me as they are two types of glue objects bridging the gap between components. Maybe it doesn't really matter, but I'm wondering what Stack Overflow has to say about it.

I used to place Converters in the ViewModel namespace, because they are often reusable even if the View changes. However, I see more and more comments placing them closer to the Views. See top answers to:
[Should your ViewModel expose XAML elements as properties or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1007767/92430)
[How can WPF Converters be used in an MVVM pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1007580/92430)

Commands are usually exposed by ViewModels to implement UI events, so I placed them in the ViewModel namespace as well. A classic examples are the [RelayCommands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030). Then I came across an interesting pattern to use Commands to display dialogs between the main view and the ViewModel. I find that just brilliant by its simplicity. The command is really just a proxy, but clearly in UI land. Yay or nay? See:
[MVVM and Dialogs](http://www.daedtech.com/mvvm-and-dialogs)
[Handling Dialogs in WPF with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8172200/92430)

So where do you think Commands and Converters should live in MVVM? View? ViewModel? Doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you could say they are in one camp or the other. As you said, their purpose is to make the bridge between the ViewModel and the View, while keeping them uncoupled. And in my opinion that's how you should treat them, as glue code.

**Converters** - you could argue that they are closer to the view because their responsibility is related to how the information is adapted in order to be easily bound and displayed in xaml controls.

Furthermore, you could theoretically use two different converters for the same ViewModel property, depending on how you want to view it.

But nothing is stopping you to use them in other contexts if the need arises, somewhere where the View is not involved at all.

Since your question also implied where to put them, I put my converters separately, not in the views folder, nor in the ViewModels folder, to facilitate reuse.

**Commands** - are usually exposed by the ViewModel in MVVM, so that can be an argument that they are closer to the ViewModel, but in my experience, they are used most often to facilitate calling logic from the ViewModel via Bindings. If I could bind a ViewModel method call directly in xaml I would not use commands anymore - for simple cases.

Even though they are usually bound to the ViewModel, Commands might also be reusable between Views and ViewModels. If you find yourself copy-pasting the code for commands you can separate them, put the ViewModel behind an interface and reuse them.

Furthermore, the command pattern has many uses outside of the scope of MVVM. (For example, you could use it in the application logic to facilitate "Undo" functionality)

As for where to put them - usually I start by putting them in the ViewModel, and as things get more complicated I move them as needed. Here an interesting post about what you could do as things get complicated: [How can I avoid command clutter in the ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552566/how-can-i-avoid-command-clutter-in-the-viewmodel)

I know this is a subjective answer, but I hope I have provided some good arguments, and I am open to opinions.